# Check uniqueness of two Hamiltonian circuits represented by string hash

Tags: php, algorithm, hash

I'm trying to build an array with unique paths. My representation of path is a string with delimiter for example `2|3|1|4`. Which means that I can start in 2, go to 3, 1 and end my move in 4.
It's easy to detrmine if two paths equal to each other by comparing such string hash.

The problem is with comparing two Hamiltonian circuts. I use same notation like above for example `2|3|1|4` which means that I can start in 2, go to 3, 1, 4 and end my move again in 2.

Because it's a closed cycle I can also use following notation: `1|4|2|3` which means that I can start in 1, go to 4, 2, 3 and end in 1.

The order of my walk is the same in both notations as it's the same Hamiltonian cycle. However because of different start position my hashes are different. This is why I can not use them in this case to determine if both paths are equal.

Is there any algorithm which I can use to effectively compare such paths?
I can assume that maximum length of my path will be ca. 150 elements.
The only thing I come up with is to create `length - 1` possibilities of such hashes for each path.

Comment: just ensure that the smallest node in each cycle is the first (should be trivial by shifting) then your problem trivially goes away

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Sometimes the easiest solutions are the most difficult to come up with.